# Remote Desktop Log?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Is there a log or some other way to tell who has remoted in to my (xp) machine?

Answer (score 3):

To see current connections:

- open "Users" tab in Task Manager
- or use `qwinsta` on command line.

---

To register all connections (logins) to the Event Log, enable **Account login auditing** in `secpol.msc`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a codeplex project for Remote Access Monitor - you can use it to detect logins. If you aren't interested in the "monitor" side of things, you could rip out the code examples and use it to log to a file instead.

http://remoteaccessmonitor.codeplex.com/